# glBufferData fails with: "Array object is not active."

Tags: c++, opengl

EDIT: Ok, I might have found part of my mistake. I thought, that all *GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR* error messages are valid reasons to stop the execution, which is why my debug message callback was set to exit the program if it encounters *GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR*.

I can just ignore this error, as it is only severity notification, and continue, but I would still like to know what this error means and how to prevent it.

==== Original question ====

When running a relatively simple test project, I get an

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Array object is not active.
```

when running

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mesh), mesh, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

To my knowledge, I don't need an active VAO to set the VBO data, only for the *VertexAttribArray/Pointer* calls.

But even with an active/bound VAO, the same error is thrown.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
float mesh[] =
{ -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 };

{
program = glCreateProgram();

// Compile and attach shaders
...

glLinkProgram(program);

    // === Vertex Buffer ===
// Generate new buffer for vertex coordinates
glGenBuffers(1, &vb);
// Use for all ArrayBuffer operations
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);

// Runs until here. glCheckError() reports no error.
// DebugMessageCallback is also not triggered.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mesh), mesh, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't leave out any calls that may affect glBufferData in your simplified example? Calling glBufferStorage for a buffer makes it immutable. Any subsequent calls to glBufferData for that buffer result in the GL_INVALID_OPERATION error.

Comment: @LafsiIronknuckles The only parts I ommited are the marked (...) sections, and of course the context creation beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that my window manager called the draw method in a separate thread while the initialization was still ongoing.
To fix this, I added a simple isInitialized check to the draw function.